# i need to know why every time i put Z=input.nextInt(); after the second prompt it doesn't work

Tags: java

why is when i try to put `Z=input.nextInt();` after second prompt it doesn't work but when i put it the second for loop it works.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FaresMarwan_150086 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     // create Scanner to obtain input from command window
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      int M;// The normal dose entered by the user
      int endValue;// The value that stops the loop
      int sum;// sum of experiments entered by the user
      int Z;

    double percentage;// percentage of bad experiments
    double warn = 0;// initialize rule violation
    double exp = 0;// initialize experiment
    System.out.print("Please, insert the normal dose in ml: "); // prompt 
    M= input.nextInt(); // read M from the user
    System.out.println("Please, insert the set of experiments (3 integers per line, stop by 0 0 0): ");// prompt

    for(endValue=0; endValue==0;) // loop till endValue is 0
    {
        // initialization phase
        sum=0; // initialize sum
        for(int count = 0; count<=2; count++) //loop 3 times
        { 
            Z=input.nextInt(); //read z from user
            sum=sum+Z; // Sum is sum plus Z

            if(sum==0) // if the sum becomes 0
            {
                endValue++; // Increment endValue by 1
            }// end if
        }// end for
        if(sum!=0) //if the sum is not 0
        {
            exp++; // Increment exp by 1
        }

        if(sum>M) // if sum is bigger that M
        {  
            warn++; // Increment warn by 1             
        }
        if(exp==0) // if exp is 0
        {
        exp++; // Increment exp by 1
        }// end if
    }// end for
    // termination phase
    percentage =  (warn/exp)*100; // divide warn on exp and multiply that by 100
    System.out.printf("The percentage of bad experiments is %.2f%%  .\n" ,percentage);
    }// end main method 
  }// end class FaresMarwan_150086
```

Comment: I didn't understand the question. What does `it doesn't work` mean ?

Comment: I agree, if it doesn't work, then explain what errors you get or what happens.

Comment: ok so when i put Z=input.nextInt() under System.out.println("please< insert the set .........") in the output i get infinite loop(when i put 0 0 0 at the end the program doesn't stop) but when it's after  for(int count=0; count<=2; count++) it stops when you put 0 0 0 at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input.nextInt(); only takes in one int

From your comments, it looks like you're requesting the user to input 3 numbers at once with a space, e.g. 1 2 3

If you put input.nextInt() before the for loop, Z = 1

However when you put the input.nextInt() in the for loop it will grab the 3 integers you have input because you are calling input.nextInt() 3 times.

Comment: oh thanks man now i get it. one last question by the way if we change the for loop to a while loop and put the Z=input.nextInt() inside the while loop will that work as well?

Comment: No problem. I believe could create two more variables e.g X and Y and call X = input.nextInt(), Y = input.nextInt(), Z = input.nextInt() all before the for loop. A while loop could work.